# EF CodeFirst migrations not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am using EF 6 code first .
I have changed my DbContext to pass connction string to constructor

```
public class EFDbContext : DbContext
{
    public EFDbContext(string connectionString)
        : base(connectionString)
    {
        Database.Connection.ConnectionString = connectionString;
    }
    public EFDbContext()
    {
    }

    public DbSet<MC_Users> MCUsers { get; set; }
}
```

and moved connection string from Web.Config

Everything was working fine. But adding one more property to MC_Users,
is not effecting the database, i mean the code first is not working.

```
 add-migration test    command created a new DbMigration class test
 update-database command applied it successfully
```

but my database table is not changing

Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are changing local sqlexpress database. You need to provide custom connection string to Update-Database cmdlet:

Update-Database **-ConnectionString**

http://coding.abel.nu/2012/03/ef-migrations-command-reference/#Update-Database

Also you can use DbMigrator class to do migration from code without using Update-Database cmdlet. When you use DbMigrator class you need to set dbMigrator.Configuration.TargetDatabase to change default connection string.

```
var dbMigrator = new DbMigrator(new Configuration());
dbMigrator.Configuration.TargetDatabase = //New connection settings goes here.
dbMigrator.Configuration.AutomaticMigrationDataLossAllowed = true;
dbMigrator.Update();
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.migrations.dbmigrator(v=vs.113).aspx

Comment: Thanks for the help, But i am giving connection string from code. So dont have a connection string name in app config or web config .Then how can i give Update-Database -ConnectionString ConnectionString name

Comment: For migrations to work, you should add connection string to the web.config.

Comment: pravpab, there are only three ways that you can provide connection string if you are using powershell cmdlet Update-Database: 1. By providing it in a configuration file, 2. hard code it in default constructor of the DbContext class. 3. Pass it to the cmdlet using ConnectionString parameter.

Answer (score 1):

In order to make your migration works, you **must** add connection string to the web.config/app.config of your project that is set up as a "Startup Project". After setting these, on the package manager console you should choose DbContext project and try Update-Database method.

Comment: I had selected the correct project in the "Default project" dropdown on the Package Manager Console, but it wasn't enough - setting the project as the Startup Project did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Leaving an answer here as I had a similar problem that wasn't solved by the accepted answer:

I had the password wrong in the app.config I was using against a different environment. Get-Migrations doesn't give you an error about failed credentials, it just tells you "No migrations have been applied to the target database", which is hugely misleading.

Hopefully someone else who comes across this will discover it's as simple as a typo in their connection string!

To the mod who deleted this:

> Please don't post identical answers to multiple questions. Post one good answer, then vote/flag to close the other questions as duplicates. If the question is not a duplicate, tailor your answers to the question.

It's not a duplicate answer from another question; it's an alternate answer to this one. I had this problem at work, but the accepted solution wasn't the answer for me. This is simply another option for someone to check if they stumble upon this question.